# What kind of legal protection can I obtain for a user interface design?

Tags: legal

I'm looking to protect an innovative user interface design idea for a mobile application. It took a lot of work and creative effort to come up with a design that satisfies the particular constraints I'm working under, and I would like to protect the design from copy-cat attempts.

Since the design will be used globally, this is a generic question, but the most important markets are the US and EU, so I would prefer details that apply specifically there.

Answer (score 7):

**In the EU and [Germany](http://www.dpma.de/english/patent/patent_protection/european_and_international_patent/index.html)** you can protect your design. [There is no rule for all](http://www.epo.org/service-support/faq/basics.html#faq-197), but [several national laws](http://oami.europa.eu/EN/office/diff/pdf/National_law.pdf).

As far as I understood [the process](http://oami.europa.eu/ows/rw/pages/RCD/legalReferences/guidelines.en.do), you are going to [protect your design following this guide](http://oami.europa.eu/en/office/aspects/pdf/ExamGuidelines.pdf). There will be no examination for the uniqueness of your design nor a protection for duplicates in terms of secureness. If a possible duplicate exist, you have to prove your uniqueness at the court.

For an idea what this means, I give you an example of German law, which is the biggest economy in Europe btw.

In Germany you can protect design, if...

> A design must be new [...] This means that no design that is identical or differing only in immaterial details from the design applied for has been published[...]
>
> Furthermore, the design must have individual character [...in the eye of...] the so-called "informed user" [...]
>
> [But] novelety and individual character are not examined by the German Patent [...] [It] will be examined by the civil courts when there is a dispute [...]

Source [German Patent and Trademark Office - Design | Page 6](http://www.dpma.de/docs/service/veroeffentlichungen/broschueren_en/designs_engl.pdf)

- That means you have to show your design **first** to DPMA or european equivalent.
- It has to be **unique for a normal user**.
- It shouldn't differ in immaterial details only. What that means in terms of software is a hard question. Best you ask a lawyer for it.
- And in case of doubt, you have to go through the courts to protect your design and prove your uniqueness.

But there is a common workaround for the gaps, that exist if you protect a design: Usually you go for a patent, if you want to secure your software, not design only!

> Discoveries, mathematical methods, **computer programs** and business methods as such **are not regarded as inventions**.

Source: [European Patent Office](http://www.epo.org/service-support/faq/basics.html#faq-197).

But a patent has to offer a unique solution to a technical problem. Which isn't done by a software only. So you fill a patent for the whole computer system as well as your software running on it. You secure the computer AND the software as a complete system. Thus you have proven your technical and material side of your invention and its patentable.

And going this way, you [can protect it easily EU-wide](http://www.epo.org/service-support/faq/basics.html#faq-196).
Nevertheless, you definitely need a lawyer for the whole process.

Sidenote: As far as I know, a behaviour like Apple's elastic drawback at end of lists can't be protected in the EU. May be they did it nevertheless.

Edit: Just read a [(german) article](http://www.heise.de/tp/artikel/37/37887/1.html) about the issue, that you can't easily fill a patent for software in Europe. It mentioned, that even Konrad Zuse recalled his patent claim, because it needed to much time and it wasn't sure he obtains a patent on his invention - the first computer Zuse Z3. Probably [the first patent claim in computer history (german only, but worth a quick look)](http://www.zib.de/zuse/Inhalt/Texte/Chrono/40er/Pdf/0229.pdf).

***Important: This isn't a legal advice as I'm not a lawyer or in this matter somehow. It's my personal opinion only.***

Comment: +1 for good references and an honest answer. Was this just through research or do you have experience dealing with this first hand?

Comment: I haven't patented a software (as a system) yet, but was very close. So just research.